# Presenting results of estimation with sub-sampling

Tags: regression, bootstrap, subsampling, presentation

I have a dataset that we can partition between three groups: Controls, Treated 1 and Treated 2.

I want to run regressions that include the whole Control and Treated 1 groups, but I draw a random sample from Treated 2 of the same size as Treated 1.
Then I regress my outcome on dummies for Treated 1 and Treated 2, together with controls.
I repeat this procedure several times, drawing a new sub-sampled for Treated 2 each time.

For the moment, I present the results indicating the average coefficient of Treated 1 and Treated 2, together with their average p-values.

Is this the most meaningful way to present the results?
What I would like to highlight is that Treatment 1 is, in general, not significant, whereas Treatment 2 is significant.

Comment: What is the goal of your analysis? Are you trying to compare the groups to each other? What does the data consist of that you have?

Comment: As part of a project, I divided the treated population according to their exposure to the treatment, creating the Treated 1 (low exposure, say the lowest decile) and Treated 2 (the remaining treated).


Regressions indicate that Treated 1 is not significant, whereas Treated 2 is. However, there is an important imbalance in the size of both groups, and I wanted to check (and show), that restricting the Treated 2 to be of the same size as Treated 1 (and letting the remaining Treated 2 be part of the Control group) generated similar results.

Comment: So is the exposure to the treatment a continuous variable or a continuous one that you forced into categories?

Comment: The exposure is continuous, and I divide the Treated between subgroups according to some cut-off value of exposure.
However, in the regression I use dummies: not-treated, short treatment, long treatment.

Comment: Why not model the exposure directly?

Comment: I've done that already. Here the idea is to check whether abandoned sites (with short treatment) procured the same effect as non-abandoned sites, with the goal of partially dismissing endogeneity concerns: if selected places that were abandoned raised the outcome, this would indicate that some underlying forces guided the choice of the place. It follows the approach here https://doi.org/10.1093/qje/qjy024
But I wanted to compare the same number of units, so that low significance in one group cannot be blamed on its small size.